# Android Bitmap recycling

Tags: android, garbage-collection, android-bitmap

**Disclaimer**: I read about 20 existing questions. Unfortunately none of them solved my problem.

I have an activity. This activity gets a Bitmap from a global/static class C and sets the bitmap to an `ImageView`. When the activity is finished and I try to reopen the activity, I get the `java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap` exception. I don't call `Bitmap.recycle()` at any point. Also, I do not delete the bitmap reference in class C. I tried the following but they didn't work:

- Call `ImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false)`
- Before setting the bitmap for `ImageView`, make a deep copy (via `Bitmap.copy()` method)

Also, I put some log statements throughout the activity lifecycle. Inside `onDestroy()`, before calling `super.onDestroy()` I check and make sure that the bitmap is not recycled (through `Bitmap.isRecycled()`)

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit turned out to be `RemoteControlClient.MetadataEditor.apply()`, it does call `recycle()` for bitmaps passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with ImageViews when reopening the activity (e.g. after screen is waked). The problem lies not in Bitmap itself, but in ImageView. My solution was to set ImageView's setImageBitmap to null on activity's onPause() and call setImageBitmap(theBitmap) on activity's onResume().